# How to square a logarithmic expression?

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I am trying to solve the following:

$$\left[\dfrac{((5+7\ln6)^2)}{14}\right] - \left[\dfrac{((5+7\ln4)^2)}{14}\right]$$

I know that this becomes:

$$\dfrac{1}{14}[5+7\ln6 + 5+7\ln4] x [5+7\ln6 - 5+7\ln4]$$

But I can't figure out how or what steps to take to get to that point. Can someone explain or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please improve the MathJax

Comment: I think your second parenthesis should be $(5+7\ln6-5-7\ln4)$ rather than $(5+7\ln6-5+7\ln4)$. With that aside, using the identity of difference of squares, namely: $a^{2}-b^{2}=(a+b)(a-b)$, should give you the result.